# Ubuntu Software Updater does nothing on clicking Upgrade button

Tags: 22.04, do-release-upgrade

I'm trying to update from Ubuntu 20.04.5 to 22.04 and Upgrade button on Software updater does nothing. Also, the terminal commands - `sudo do-release-upgrade` `sudo do-release-upgrade -d`, do nothing except show the message `Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.` Please help

The terminal output -

```
(base) ashutosh@ashutosh-Lenovo-G50-80:~$ sudo apt-mark showhold
(base) ashutosh@ashutosh-Lenovo-G50-80:~$ sudo apt full-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libfwupdplugin1
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following packages have been kept back:
  r-base-dev
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
(base) ashutosh@ashutosh-Lenovo-G50-80:~$ sudo apt install update-manager-core
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
update-manager-core is already the newest version (1:20.04.10.10).
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libfwupdplugin1
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
(base) ashutosh@ashutosh-Lenovo-G50-80:~$ sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Failed to connect to https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts. Check your Internet connection or proxy settings
There is no development version of an LTS available.
To upgrade to the latest non-LTS development release 
set Prompt=normal in /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades.
(base) ashutosh@ashutosh-Lenovo-G50-80:~$ sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
(base) ashutosh@ashutosh-Lenovo-G50-80:~$ sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
(base) ashutosh@ashutosh-Lenovo-G50-80:~$ df -H
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            8.3G     0  8.3G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.7G  2.6M  1.7G   1% /run
/dev/sda11      114G   89G   20G  83% /
tmpfs           8.4G  640M  7.8G   8% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.3M  4.1k  5.3M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           8.4G     0  8.4G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0      132k  132k     0 100% /snap/bare/5
/dev/loop2      120M  120M     0 100% /snap/core/13425
/dev/loop1      120M  120M     0 100% /snap/core/13308
/dev/loop5      171M  171M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/145
/dev/loop3       59M   59M     0 100% /snap/core18/2409
/dev/loop4       59M   59M     0 100% /snap/core18/2538
/dev/loop7      173M  173M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/161
/dev/loop6       66M   66M     0 100% /snap/core20/1611
/dev/loop8       66M   66M     0 100% /snap/core20/1593
/dev/loop9      230M  230M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/72
/dev/loop10     230M  230M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/77
/dev/loop11     421M  421M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/112
/dev/loop12     364M  364M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/115
/dev/loop16     132k  132k     0 100% /snap/hello-world/29
/dev/loop15     132k  132k     0 100% /snap/hello-world/27
/dev/loop13      97M   97M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
/dev/loop14      86M   86M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1534
/dev/loop19      54M   54M     0 100% /snap/snap-store/547
/dev/loop18      55M   55M     0 100% /snap/openstackclients/278
/dev/loop20      57M   57M     0 100% /snap/snap-store/558
/dev/loop17      51M   51M     0 100% /snap/openstackclients/134
/dev/sda2       269M   37M  232M  14% /boot/efi
tmpfs           1.7G  4.1k  1.7G   1% /run/user/1001
tmpfs           1.7G   46k  1.7G   1% /run/user/1000
(base) ashutosh@ashutosh-Lenovo-G50-80:~$ less /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
(base) ashutosh@ashutosh-Lenovo-G50-80:~$ sudo do-release-upgrade -d
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
(base) ashutosh@ashutosh-Lenovo-G50-80:~$ sudo apt-get clean
(base) ashutosh@ashutosh-Lenovo-G50-80:~$ sudo do apt-get update
sudo: do: command not found
(base) ashutosh@ashutosh-Lenovo-G50-80:~$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libfwupdplugin1
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following packages have been kept back:
  r-base-dev
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
(base) ashutosh@ashutosh-Lenovo-G50-80:~$ sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
(base) ashutosh@ashutosh-Lenovo-G50-80:~$ sudo do-release-upgrade -d
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
(base) ashutosh@ashutosh-Lenovo-G50-80:~$ sudo update-manager -d
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
```

Tried again -

```
(base) ashutosh@ashutosh-Lenovo-G50-80:~$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease    
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]        
Hit:4 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt focal-pgdg InRelease          
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [108 kB]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [278 kB]
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [391 kB]
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [944 B]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [8,004 B]
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [30.5 kB]
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [40.7 kB]
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [77.4 kB]
Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2,464 B]
Fetched 1,164 kB in 5s (255 kB/s)   
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
1 package can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see it.
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt focal-pgdg InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
(base) ashutosh@ashutosh-Lenovo-G50-80:~$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libfwupdplugin1
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following packages have been kept back:
  r-base-dev
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
(base) ashutosh@ashutosh-Lenovo-G50-80:~$ sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
(base) ashutosh@ashutosh-Lenovo-G50-80:~$
```

Comment: did you *install all available updates for your release before upgrading*? try `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` first.

Comment: @Esther Yes, I tried everything. Added output

Comment: Stop using the `-d` flag until you really understand what it does.

Comment: Your output clearly shows the reason that `do-release-upgrade` is refusing to run: `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.` It even tells you the name of the package: `r-base-dev`. One assumes you read your output; why have you not uninstalled that package?